# Integrals of asymptotically equivalent functions

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Suppose $f,g$ are continuous complex valued functions and  $f(x)$ behaves like $g(x)$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, i.e., $f(x)/g(x)\rightarrow c$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ for some constant $c>0$.  If $|\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx|<M_1<\infty$ for some constant $M_1$, is it true that $|\int_{a}^\infty g(x)dx|<M_2<\infty$ for some constants $a$ and $M_2$? Note that we do not assume here that $\int_0^\infty|f(x)|dx<\infty.$

Comment: The naive thing to try would be to apply the fact that (ignoring the possibility of division by zero), $|g|/|f| \to 1/c$, and conclude that there exists $c'$ (possibly larger than $1/c$) such that $|g/f| \leq c'$ and so $|g| \leq c' |f|$ everywhere. Then $ \int_0^\infty |g| dx \leq c' \int_0^\infty |f| dx$. Does this work? If not, can you modify it at all to work?

Comment: Here f and g are complex valued functions.

Comment: You're right, I made the tweak. It isn't especially consequential in this context, unless you are interested in the case where $\int_0^\infty f dx$ converges non-absolutely (in which case you should really spell that out so that no one assumes that you're talking about Lebesgue integration).

Comment: I do not assume $\int_0^\infty|f|dx<\infty.$

Comment: Spell that out in the question then. Commonly people will assume that $\int |f| dx < \infty$ is implicit in the assumption that $\int f dx$ exists since this is baked into the definitions in Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Here, f and g are complex but their ratio has a limit that is a strictly positive real constant value.